# Documentation of classes and modules in YUIDocs

Tags: javascript, yui, documentation-generation

I'm having a bit of trouble writing my documentation for a set of grouped modules. I think it's partly a misconception over what `@class`, `@module` and `@namespace` represent. (Or maybe it's a result of Yahoo trying to shoehorn a 'classical' language vocabulary into JS.)

I've got a roughed out sample below showing how most of my code is written and my attempt at documenting it in YUIDoc-style. The first two parts (`Foo` and `BazManager`) are pretty straightforward. To me:

- `Foo` is a `@class`;
- `Baz` is a `@class`;
- `BazManager` is a `@module` (or maybe a `@class` that contains only `@static` members);
- `Qux` is also a `@module` but contains only methods.

My problems are:

1. If `BazManager` is a `@module`, `Foo` shows up under `BazManager`;
2. If `BazManager` is a `@class`, the methods inside `Baz` get sucked into it if you don't add `@for` to everything;
3. If `BazManager` is a `@class`, then documenting `Baz`'s visibility becomes really tricky;
4. I really don't know how I'm supposed to document `Qux`. It seems to me to be a module, but since it has no `@class`es, it gobbles everything around it, including `BazManager`. So it must be a `@class`.

Can anyone suggest how I should be doing this? I don't really care if I get the terms right as long as everything in the documentation gets generated correctly.

Here's my sample code:

```
// File: Widgets.js

/**
MyNamespace namespace
@namespace MyNamespace
*/
var MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};

//--------------------PART 1: Foo-------------------//

/**
This is a description of Foo.
@class Foo
*/
MyNamespace.Foo = function () {
    this.toString = function () {
        return "I am a foo";
    };

    /**
    This is Foo's private method description.
    @method privateMethod
    @private
    */
    var privateMethod = function () {};

    /**
    This is Foo's public method description.
    @method publicMethod
    */
    this.publicMethod = function () {};
};


//--------------------PART 2: Baz-------------------//
/**
This is a description of BazManager.
@module BazManager
@namespace MyNamespace
*/
MyNamespace.BazManager = (function () {
    var self = {};

    /**
    This is a description of Baz.
    @class Baz
    */
    var Baz = function (type) {
        /**
        toString description
        @method toString
        @returns {String}
        */
        this.toString = function () {
            return "I am a baz and I'm " + type;
        };
    };

    /**
    This is BazManager's privateBaz description.
    @method privateBaz
    @private
    */
    var privateBaz = new Baz("private");

    /**
    This is BazManager's publicBaz description.
    @method publicBaz
    */
    self.publicBaz = new Baz("public");

    return self;
} ());


//--------------------PART 3: Qux-------------------//

MyNamespace.Qux = (function () {
    var self = {};
    /**
    execute description
    @method execute
    @private
    */
    var execute = function () {
        console.log("Qux is done");
    };

    /**
    start description
    @method start
    */
    self.start = function () {
        setTimeout(execute, 1000);
    };

    return self;
} ());
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the classes in separate files?

Comment: No, but I don't think documentation should enforce a project layout. I'm beginning to suspect that in my code, `MyNamespace` actually is the module and all of `Foo`, `BazManager` and `Qux` are `@class`es.

Comment: Yeah, I think your comment is the answer. Look at what YUI Doc says about modules in [the syntax ref](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/syntax/index.html): It requires a module per source tree and that it sometimes is not obvious what is a module. Let MyNameSpace be a module and a namespace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In YUIDoc `@class` is used for both classical classes and for objects which contain a bunch of methods. Classes that are meant to be instantiated are also marked with `@constructor`. That's mostly because of the way that those classes are then shown in the templates. It's a lot easier to track down a class than many lone functions.

The YUI team and many in the community (myself included) seem to be moving away from `@namespace`. It's hard to get right. Instead we're writing class names with dots in them, ie: `@class Plugin.NodeMenuNav`.

Modules are meant in the YUI sense and can be mostly understood as "scripts" that contain one or more classes.

So a typical module will look like this:

```
/**
A series of utilities to do stuff

@module Stuff
**/

/**
A class that does foo very well

@class Foo
@constructor
@param {Object} [config] Configuration object
@param {Boolean} [config.jumpHigh] Whether foo should jump really high
**/
function Foo(config) {
  config = config || {};
  var high = config.jumpHigh;
}
/**
@method jump
@chainable
**/
Foo.prototype.jump = function () {
    // jump
    return this;
};

/**
A series of utilities to make Foo do more stuff

@class FooUtils
**/
var FooUtils = {
    /**
    @method doSomeStuff
    @static
    **/
    doSomeStuff: function () {

    }
};
```

Finally, `@for` is meant for modules that extend other modules. For instance, you could have a module Bar that adds methods to the prototype of Foo:

```
/**
Adds extra functionality to Foo

@module Bar
**/

/**
Run really fast

@method run
@for Foo
**/
Foo.prototype.run = function () {};bv
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. That's more or less what I ended up doing (it was the only way I could get things to show up accurately). For what it's worth for anyone who comes across this question, `@for` is also useful if you have some methods for an enclosing class/constructor that come **after** some inner classes/constructors. Without it, those methods will get attached to the last inner class. I think the documentation mentions this in a couple places, but someone might not have immediately appreciated what they meant.